# Не могу создать сущность

Tags: c#, uml

Не могу понять как мне реализовать следующую сущность. Есть главное устройство, к нему могут быть подключены 1-30 подчиненных устройств - это будут устройства 1 уровня(Каждое устройство имеет адрес, флаг на поиск нижестоящих устройств и адрес интерфейса. А к этим 30 устройствам могут также быть подключены еще 30 устройств. И так далее до 8 уровня. То есть на 8 уровне может быть 30 в степени 8 устройств. При нажатии на кнопку начнется поиск дерева устройств и формирование какой-то сущности. Проблема в том что я не могу представить эту сущность. Будет большая вложенность.

Comment: "...формирование какой-то сущности." и какой-же сущности? Какие данные она должна включать в себя? Ваш вопрос понятен только про факт вложенности, дальше нет. Так что же вы хотите получить?

Comment: @Bulson с главного устройства обращаться на 1 уровень к любому устройству а из этих устройств обращаться  каждый к своему списку подчиненных устройств  2 уровня и так далее

Comment: Тут надо вспомнить, по всей видимости, про "связанный список".

Comment: @Bulson Спасибо, вроде я сам разобрался, но и ваша подсказка будет кстати.